# RabbitMQ.Client: reuse IModel for few EventingBasicConsumer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, rabbitmq

I use [official rabbit client for .net](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client). I have `20` queues in `rabbitmq` instance. If I create `IModel` per queue consumer like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
   var model = _connection.CreateModel();
   var cns = new EventingBasicConsumer(model);
   ch.BasicConsume("queue_" + i, false, cns);
   ...
}
```

Application uses `37` threads.

If I reuse the same `IModel` for all consumers:

```
var model = _connection.CreateModel();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{   
   var cns = new EventingBasicConsumer(model);
   ch.BasicConsume("queue_" + i, false, cns);
   ...
}
```

Application uses `18` threads.

Is it a safe and good approach to decrease the number of application threads?

I count the number of threads using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count`.

I checked threads in `dottrace`: in the 1st case there are 20 threads created by `RabbitMQ.Client` with name like **WorkPool-Session#1:Connection(guid-here),amqp://1.1.1.1:5672** , in the 2nd case - only one such thread.

**UPDATE**: Posted the question in [official rabbitmq google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/mQ8nm7o3pz0).

Comment: Finally we implemented two options to optimize thread allocation: `1.` reuse the same channel (`IModel`) between diffrenet consumers (don't forget to set `global=false` for `QoS`)  and `2.` consuming with  `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer`. It's configured in settings. We'll check which one is the best for us.